# Using the keyboard module in Python 3.8 on Mac

Tags: python, python-3.x, keyboard

I am trying to write a code that allows me to make a keyboard press to trigger an output. I am trying to use the keyboard module to do this, but every time I try to run it I get an error that says:

File "/Users/julietdenapoli/Desktop/keyboard.py", line 10, in from msvcrt import getch ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'msvcrt'

I kept noticing that the issue was coming from the import keyboard, so I literally just tried to run a one line code:

```
import keyboard
```

And I still get that same error. I did pip install keyboard, not really sure why I am running into this error?

Comment: You also need to `pip install msvcrt`

Comment: @GAEfan. I got another error when I tried that:   ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement msvcrt (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for msvcrt.                      Is this because I'm using a Mac? I thought I maybe read somewhere you can't use it on Mac.